# ability to make a border around the attached image

Tags: feature-request, images

Like me, who frequently put some screenshot/images in the questions/answers.. need this functionality - in most cases,  screenshots areas contain some texts and viewers 
[image]

Answer (score 8):

It feels like you're optimizing a use case which we explicitly don't want to optimize.

Basically, if the OP puts a picture of their code, of their text, or anything that we would reasonably want to copy into our own system, **the OP has not done their part** in placing all of the relevant code and information into the question.

Your gut reaction when you see a question like this should be to close it until they actually put their code in from the image.  Decorating it only further obviates the problem.

Comment: It depends a lot on context.  For example, on meta people screenshot stackoverflow.com all the time, and screenshots of the site that you're on can be...confusing.  On main, it depends a lot on tags; in some tags screenshots, including screenshots of text, are indeed very rare, but in other cases *valid* use cases are common enough.  For example, in UI frameworks, or questions about UI implementation, often need screenshots, not uncommonly about text.

Comment: you havent mentioned about cons of the feature. if it needs developers hard work or has any cons, then i understand your answer.

Answer (score 7):

In the category awful tricks until your FR gets implemented:

[image]

---

Markdown:

```
<kbd>

![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtiwC.png)

</kbd>
```

When used, unicorns will hunt you in your sleep forever.

Comment: Oh that's nice too.

Comment: @Mat I like yours better but the voting is off on Meta, again.

Comment: Oh dear - this anti-semantic hack [has got out into the wild](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404853/title-quality-warning-says-your-question-even-when-editing-someone-elses-que). I don't recommend people do this - what would screen-readers make of it?

Comment: Screen-readers stutter for a bit and then continue with a slight lisp ...

Comment: Can I just... delete this? :-( [My keyboard doesn't have this key](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404435).

Answer (score 4):

Quote highlighting like this:

> [image: hmm]

is often enough.

Comment: don't you see the border around the image above?

Comment: actually, quoting is a different kind of action , and in such case, you are  quoting has a different meaning, and to use it "as a trick" is not a good idea.

Comment: @T.Todua if you want something that works now this answer solves your problem. Your FR will need many 6 to 8 weeks before it is implemented.