# Using Keyboard Format for Product Names

Tags: discussion, formatting

I have seen people format product names with the keyboard format.  <kbd>ExcelO365</kbd> for example.  I assumed this was the standard based the reputation of the people I saw doing this.  Did I assume wrong?

Comment: In my opinion it's abuse of formatting. Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text

Comment: Most of the times a product name doesn't really need special formatting. Occasionally I find bold or italics useful if there are several names and they should stand out. But anything other than that seems excessive.

Comment: Yes. Product names do not need any special formatting. At all.

Comment: Unless there’s a literal `ExcelO365` button or key, this is incorrect formatting. I have no idea what the relation to reputation is. Can you show an example? Are you referring to [Extracting strings between specific characters in excel and separating them with a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65557008/1)?

Comment: There are a couple of posts by that user with this incorrect formatting: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65682721/4642212) should be “`FILTERXML()`” instead, or better “`FILTERXML`”, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65682663/4642212) should be simply “Excel 365” instead.

Comment: Only use keyboard formatting for keyboard keys. Only use code formatting for code. Only use quote formatting for quotes. This shouldn't be as complicated as people make it.

Comment: Looks like an odd quirk the user has [1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65682663/1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65593022/1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65592840/1) for some examples. They probably just need to be politely information that the `kbd` markup means "keyboard" and that there are no Excel365/Excel365 keys; and so suggesting people press them is incorrect formatting. :)

Comment: @John Montgomery: What about buttons in a GUI, e.g., *"Next"*, *"Save"*, *"OK"*, *"Close"*, *"Don't Save"*,  and *"Cancel"* (literal text. In, say, Visual Studio)? [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8/12859334#12859334)

Comment: (The ultimate is [castle building](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-too-intrusive/1974#1974).)

Comment: This is an incredibly obnoxious practice that adds nothing to the content here. Is a mod going to reach out to this user and inform them not to do this? Paging @CodyGray...

Comment: If you want a moderator to reach out to a user, flag one of their posts and note a pattern of abuse, please, @IanKemp. Although, often repeatedly having their posts edited sends a stronger message.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I want to quote a couple of comments here, which contain the answer to the question:

> Yes. Product names do not need any special formatting. At all.
> –[Heretic Monkey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey)

They need only be capitalized (or, more accurately, rendered in the canonical form used by the company), since they are proper nouns (and often trademarked and/or copyrighted). The capital letters provide enough distinction within and relative to the surrounding text.

> Unless there’s a literal `ExcelO365` button or key, this is incorrect formatting.
> –[Sebastian Simon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/sebastian-simon)

(Hint: There isn't any such key or button. This is incorrect formatting, just as [it's incorrect to use code formatting for anything other than actual code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text))

There is no relation to reputation; just because a user has been around a while doesn't mean that they are doing everything correctly.

> Only use keyboard formatting for keyboard keys. Only use code formatting for code. Only use quote formatting for quotes. This shouldn't be as complicated as people make it.
> –[John Montgomery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7496073/john-montgomery)

In general, you want to minimize the amount of formatting you use. Making a half-dozen words bold in every sentence does not improve readability. If anything, it tarnishes it. Emphasis is only emphatic if used sparingly. That is aside from the issue of *semantic correctness*, brought up by John Montgomery, which is really the most important—and also the easiest decision rule.

Comment: *need only be capitalized* — I'd urge caution on this, as the capitalization (if any!) of a company does not always follow normal grammar rules (for as much as those exist). Examples like "eBay" or "id Software".

Comment: True, @Shepmaster. In general, absent any specific trademark guidance, proper nouns are capitalized. But the specific trademark guidance should always be followed. It is irritating when my grandmother emails about a problem with her "I-pad".

Comment: @Shepmaster wait, are you telling me that LaTeX isn't a proper grammar rule? InSaNiTy!

Answer (score 38):

<kbd>Don't do that, please!</kbd>
Keyboard formatting is for keys and buttons (menu items) only.

**OK:**
<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>
<kbd>RETURN</kbd>
<kbd>File</kbd><kbd>Save</kbd>
ExcelO365
Microsoft

**Not OK:**
<kbd>ExcelO365</kbd>
<kbd>Microsoft</kbd>

Comment: Where can I purchase a keyboard with File and Save keys?

Comment: @VGR It says **buttons**.

Comment: Nitpick: **File** and **Save** aren't buttons in Win32, but menu items.

Comment: @VGR Buy a Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000, then you can spend a fun few minutes remapping the keys `[Help]` ... `[Print]` one by one back into `[F1]` ... `[F12]` so you won't keep trying to figure out why nothing happened when you tried to debug or step into source code and the `[F Lock]` got disabled again. Worth it though - such a comfortable keyboard! (`[Save]` is `[F11]` there)

Comment: is `<kbd>any</kbd>` acceptable for "press any key"? 

Comment: `<kbd>` is for physical keys or your keyboard or device, hence `KeyBoarD`. It is not for buttons or menu items on the screen, in my opinion. Not that it matters that much.

Comment: @Larnu having a look at my keyboard I can see " e s c ", " c a t a r l"  and " p i g u p ".  But not any key. Are those related?

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Counterpoint: You should use the <kbd> tag for *everything*. Its compact size optimizes screen real estate, and the subtle embossing effect helps with readability (and tactility, for those with synesthesia). Now, it's important to use the 
<br/> tag, because the text doesn't wrap otherwise. Or just remember to</kbd><kbd>reopen the tag sometimes.</kbd>
<kbd>The one thing to keep in mind is that this is the *keyboard* tag. It's not intended for anything other than rendering text which is present on a key.</kbd><kbd>So in order to use it properly, you'll first need to own a keyboard which happens to have your chosen text printed on one of the keys. (As I do. I use the "reopen the tag sometimes" key frequently.)</kbd>
<kbd>You're on the honor system, though. Don't abuse it.</kbd>